# Swipe Refresh Layout retry progress bar after (x) minutes

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, retrypolicy

I read documentation of `SwipeRefreshLayout`but couldn't find any method for `RetryPolicy`. I want SwipeRefreshLayout to show retry in `progressbar` if data isn't fetched in 5 seconds.

Any guideliness

Comment: It doesn't provide it actually. You have to do it manually by scheduling some handler or other mechanism.

Comment: agree with @Wizard

Answer (score 1):

As @Wizard said, you can do it something like this.

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(data_isnt_fetched){

                 //Fetch data again

              }
        }
    }, 5000); //5sec
```

Comment: @Ubaid if you go this way, I recommend you to keep a reference to the handler, and a reference to the callback (the runnable), so you can always remove the callback in case the activity is destroyed: under onDestroy() _mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRetryCallback);_